# New Rails Project on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to run my first rails project which "hello world!" but i think there is some problems..

I have installed ruby, rails, apache, mysql, by rvm.

I use these command to start my project

```
rails new hello
```

and here is the output:

```
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install --local
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

At the last line, there is an error. Also my server does not work. I cant access localhost:3000

Please help me, I am working on that for 2 days :)

Comment: type rvm list in your terminal. And show me the result..

Comment: rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Comment: you have installed ruby 1.9.3. but its searching for ruby 1.9.1

Comment: So i should change default version for ruby but how?

Comment: thats why it's throwing error.. if u want, install ruby 1.9.1. else before creating project type this line . rvm use 1.9.3

Comment: @Mehmet do not edit the title, but accept the answer (click on the check at the left of the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have install ruby 1.9.3. but its searching for ruby 1.9.1

so, If you want to use 1.9.1 then install ruby 1.9.1 using rvm. else type the below command before creating project.

```
 rvm use 1.9.3
```

Comment: thats okey, there is no problem about creating new project. but now i cant see the localhost:3000 it does not work

Comment: start the server. type rails s

Comment: before running that comment go into the project path. if your project name is hello. type cd hello. then type rails server

Comment: i dont understand that why dont start the server.

i have www folder in my home folder, and i create a folder which name is hello. then i use these command to make a project **rails new hello** thats okey, no error. than i go to directory **cd hello** and i am trying to start server with **rails server** after that again no error but i cant access localhost:3000

Comment: maybe i should make some configuration for the server?

Comment: try with this.. rails server -p 3005   and type localhost:3005 in ur browser.

Comment: i am sorry but it does not work. what about the configuration? there some information to make config https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ruby-on-rails.html#ruby-on-rails-configuration

Comment: to simply start the server there is no need for configuration. do you have skype?